# TypeScript error: duplicate identifier, React definition files

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I work on Webstorm and I try to compile via TypeScript *.tsx.
I put react folder at the root of my project.
I imported react with the relevant typescript command.
While I tsc I get the following error:

```
react-definition/react.d.ts(2267,9): error TS2300: Duplicated identifier 'tspan'.
```

and it's pointing files in the react-definition folder.

**UPDATE:**
here is the code:

```
import * as react from "react-definition"
<div>
<Check/>
</div>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please add your code

Answer (score 0):

If you are using npm in your project, you can run the following commands (in console or terminal) to automatically add typescript definition files for react:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/react
npm install --save-dev @types/react-dom
```

Then, when importing in your code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
```

If you are not using npm already, you should initialize your project using npm. Run the following commands in your terminal or console, while in your project folder:

```
npm init
npm install --save react react-dom
npm install --save-dev typescript
```